# Not able to insert 11,000 columns data from one table to another

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have created a table1 (partitioned by batchDate and batchID), comprising of 11,000 columns. The table1 is loaded with part files by some other process, usually having 30 part files, of average size 8 MB each. I am writing a process to insert data from this table1, to another table2 after repartitioning it. I am passing a dynamic value into repartition method which means, if I am expecting all partitions of 100 MB each, I am calculating size of data present in source folder, and dividing the same by 100 MB.

So potential partitions would be = Size of source folder/100 MB, for any given batch.

But it's not even able to complete this write operation for 226 MB of data present in source folder, and is running forever.

```
val df = spark.sql("select * from table1 where batchdt='20190716' and batchid = '20190716073'")
spark.sql("set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict")
df.repartition(2).write.insertInto("table2")
```

Running the above code using config:

```
spark-shell --master yarn  --driver-memory 3g --num-executors 3 --executor-cores 3 --executor-memory 2g
```

Not sure what am I missing here. Would really appreciate any help.